# Post var javascript em PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho isto no head:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
        var country = data.country_name;
        var ip = data.ip;
        var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"file.php",
            data: {
                userCountry:country,
                userIp:ip,
                vw:w
            }
        });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Isto no file.php:

```
$maxwidth = $_POST['vw'];
$maxcountry = $_POST['userCountry'];
$maxip = $_POST['userIp'];
```

Mas o POST nunca chega lá.
Alguém ajuda?

Comment: Voce adicionou a lib jquery.js antes? Porque no meu funcionou o seu codigo

Comment: A menos que, você queira um retorno para a sua página

Answer (score 1):

O [*`$.ajax` do jQuery*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) precisa ter as funções success ou done definidas para que seja disparado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
        var country = data.country_name;
        var ip = data.ip;
        var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"file.php",
            data:{userCountry:country, userIp:ip, vw:w},
        }).done(function (resposta) {
           console.log("sucesso", resposta);
        }).fail(function (erro) {
           console.log("erro", erro.status);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

No caso usei o `.done` para pegar a resposta e o `.fail` para pegar o erro, se tiver ocorrido algum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você tenha que usar o json_decode no php:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if(property_exists($data, 'userCountry') || property_exists($data, 'userIp') || property_exists($data, 'vw')){

  $userCountry = $data->userCountry;
  $userIp = $data->userIp;
  $vw = $data->vw;

}
```

Procure usar também o console.log(); para ver se as variáveis estão com os valores certos.

```
console.log(userCountry);
console.log(userIp);
console.log(vw);
```